# IValueConverter, get other values of row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, ivalueconverter

I'm working on an C#/WPF project. I have a datagrid binded to a model.

How can I get the other values of the same row available within the converter?

Converter example:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int val = (int)value;

    return (int)(val / 0.41);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int val = (int)value;
    return (int)(val * 0.41);
}
```

Binding is done like can be seen in the
View (XAML):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FixParaCollectionView}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
       </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

How could I get other values (e.g. "Name") of the current row within the converter?

Answer (score 2):

In your TextBoxColumn, instead of Binding with Value proeperty bind to the whole DataContext of the row

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding ,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
```

Then in converter you will get the whole object backing your DataGridRow. Assuming Model is your model class

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    Model model= value as Model;

    return (int)(model.Value/ 0.41);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm searching right now how to use your answer for a DataGridTemplateColumn. Maybe someone could tell me and shorten my search.

Comment: you can use it in a same way you are doing for other templates... if you share your templatecolumn it will be easier to give you solution

Comment: <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
<helper:TemplateSelector ComboboxTemplate="{StaticResource ComboboxTemplate}" NumTemplate="{StaticResource NumTemplate}"/>

##Here is the template I want to have the converter running on...
<DataTemplate x:Key="NumTemplate">
<wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource StimVoltageConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector></DataGridTemplateColumn>

Comment: `<wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource StimVoltageConverter}}" />` doing this does not help?

Comment: This throws me an exception. Isn't there missing a comma after "Binding"? But after all it wants to have some property after the Binding. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: {"Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception."}..Inner exception: {"Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."}

Comment: <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource StimVoltageConverter}}" />... try this.. missed the comma.. this will send the whole row datacontext i.e your model instance to the converter

Comment: This does not work for "Value={Binding,...". The problem is, this only works for "Binding={Binding," I guess. Further ideas? It tells me that the "," is unexpected.

Comment: In Silverlight if you need to set a path, use path='' (single quotes)